# Sleeping / Waiting in a CUDA Thread

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to write some CUDA code to calculate the longest common subsequence. I can't work out how to make the thread sleep until the dependencies to calculate it's cell are satisfied:

i.e.

```
// Ignore the spurious maths here, very messy data structures. Planning ahead to strings that are bigger then GPU blocks. i & j are correct though.
int real_i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
int real_j = blockDim.y * (max_offset - blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.y;

char i_char = seq1[real_i];
char j_char = seq2[real_j];

// For i & j = 1 to length
if((real_i > 0 && real_j > 0) && (real_i < sequence_length && real_j < sequence_length) {

    printf("i: %d, j: %d\n", real_i, real_j);
    printf("I need to wait for dependancy at i: %d j: %d and i: %d j: %d\n", real_i, (real_j - 1), real_i - 1, real_j);
    printf("Is this true? %d\n", (depend[sequence_length * real_i + (real_j - 1)] && depend[sequence_length * (real_i - 1) + real_j]));

    //WAIT FOR DEPENDENCY TO BE SATISFIED
    //THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE CODE TO HANG
    while( (depend[sequence_length * real_i + (real_j - 1)] == false) && (depend[sequence_length * (real_i - 1) + real_j] == false) ) {
    }

    if (i_char == j_char)
        c[sequence_length * real_i + real_j] = (c[sequence_length * (real_i - 1) + (real_j - 1)]) + 1;
     else
        c[sequence_length * real_i + real_j] = max(c[sequence_length * real_i + (real_j - 1)], c[sequence_length * (real_i - 1) + real_j]);

    // SETTING THESE TO TRUE SHOULD ALLOW OTHER THREADS TO BREAK PAST THE WHILE BLOCK
    depend[sequence_length * real_i + (real_j - 1)] = true;
    depend[sequence_length * (real_i - 1) + real_j] = true;
}
```

So basically the thread should hang on the while loop until its dependencies, are satisfied by the other threads before moving into the calculation code.

I know the 'first' thread has its dependencies satisfied as it prints

```
real i 1, real j 1
I need to wait for dependancy at i: 1 j: 0 and i: 0 j: 1
Is this true? 1
```

Which once it has finished its calculation sets some cells in the dependency matrix to true allowing 2 more threads to get past the while loop and the kernel moves from there.

However if I uncomment the while loop my whole system hangs for ~10 seconds and I get

```
the launch timed out and was terminated
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's bad idea to sleep, better wait on condition variable or mutex.

On GPU every condition statement is extremely expensive. So if you can, try to parallelize all code. To make sure that code was finished in all threads you can use `__syncthreads()`

If you still want to use easiest solution add mutex, but it's generally bad idea